# getMenuInflater and ListActivity

Tags: android

I have an ActionBar. When I call

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
```

in my Activity the menu using the ActionBar, which is what I want. But when I try this in a ListActivity, the menu is added to classic menu (where I have to push the menu button...) How can I add the menu to the ActionBar in my ListActivity?

Comment: i dont know what i do? i deleted your post? ..bud i have target 14 android 4.0 https://dl.dropbox.com/u/33338943/prob.png